# Why is my jquery form not working?

Tags: jquery, forms

i made a form that works with jQuery, the submit button is disabled while all selectors have no values.

but it doesn't work =/, when all selectors have values the submit button is still disabled.
please help me to find what's wrong.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/2898/)

JS:

```
(function() {
    $('.form-valid').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('.form-valid').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: you made a keyup() event... When you change a dropdown you don't press any key

Comment: so what event should i use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two problems:

1. Your document ready wasn't technically correct.
2. You were watching [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) on `select` elements.  They don't normally have a keyup event, but rather a [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

Here's an updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/rgs7soaa/1/

And here's the updated code:

```
// Corrected the jQuery document ready.
// Originally: (function() {
jQuery(function($) {
    // Changed this from "keyup" to "change"
    $('.form-valid').change(function() {
        var empty = false;
        $('.form-valid').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.change` instead of `.keyup` for the select tag :

```
$('.form-valid').change(function() {
    var empty = false;
    $('.form-valid').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Really it should say **you should use .change**.  OP *can use* any event, but it doesn't work unless it's change....